# Open source Video Jockey software

Tags: open-source, video, video-editing

I'm looking for a Video Jockey software for a live projection video.
I only know [Resolume Arena 4](http://resolume.com/software/) but it's expensive.
So I need:

- Free Software / Cheap
- OpenSource is a must
- Compatible with Linux or Windows 7
- Not too heavy on the system